# how to organise files with python27 app engine webapp2 framework

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, webapp2

I've gone through the getting started tut for python27 and app engine: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/

By the end of the tut, all the the classes are in the same file (helloworld.py) and you and you configure the router to point a url path to a class at the bottom of the file:

```
 app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),
                           ('/sign', Guestbook)],
                          debug=True)
```

What the tut did not cover is how do I orginise my classes / files as my app grows. For example, would I put MainPage in a separate file and then call 'import MainPage' in the helloworld.py file and add the route to the WSGIApplication? Is there anything more automated than this? What should I call the MainPage file and where should I store it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Preferable to importing all of your handlers at app-startup is to take advantage of [webapp2's lazy handler loading](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/routing.html#lazy-handlers) which loads modules/packages as needed.
So you have a couple of options:

**Option 1, Handlers in a module**
Place `MainPage` in another file (module) at the same level as your `helloworld.py` file:

```
/my_gae_app
    app.yaml
    helloworld.py
    handlers.py
```

And in your routing (in `helloworld.py`) you would do:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', 'handlers.MainPage'),
                               ('/sign', 'handlers.Guestbook')],
                              debug=True)
```

---

**Option 2, Handlers in a package; perhaps consider as your app gets larger**
As your app gets larger you may wish to create a package in which to place your handlers:

```
/my_gae_app
    /handlers
        __init__.py
        guestbook.py
        main.py
    app.yaml
    helloworld.py
```

Routes (in `helloworld.py`):

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', 'handlers.main.MainPage'),
                               ('/sign', 'handlers.guestbook.Guestbook')],
                              debug=True)
```