# Using GAE Webapp2 with classes in more than one file

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I'm having problems with Webapp2. When I put handlers for URLs that point to different python files in the app.yaml I get the following error:

```
ERROR    2012-10-06 16:44:57,759 wsgi.py:203] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 195, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 250, in _LoadHandler
    __import__(cumulative_path)
ImportError: No module named application
```

My app.yaml:

```
application: [[app's name]]
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

inbound_services:
- mail

handlers:

- url: /send
  script: email.application

- url: /_ah/mail/update@sitdown-standup.appspotmail.com.*
  script: email.application

- url: /.*
  script: SDSUmodels.application

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.1"
```

SDSUmodels.py ends with:

```
application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/info', MakeBasicInfo)], 
                                   debug=True)`
```

and email.py ends with:

```
application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/request', Request_update),
                                   ('/send', Send_report),
                                   (Receive_email.mapping())], 
                                   debug=True)`
```

When I remove these lines

```
- url: /send
  script: email.application
```

from app.yaml, the error stops, but this leaves me without a way to point a URL towards a particular file.

I can see some alternative ways of handling this in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11181957/how-to-organise-files-with-python27-app-engine-webapp2-framework) but I was wondering why this approach isn't working. I've done this previously with the old webapp version in a different project and it's worked – details below.

app.yaml:

```
application: [[other app's name]]
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets

- url: /twitter
  script: twitter.py

- url: /_ah/mail/kindle@shelvdtracker.appspotmail.com.*
  script: kindle.py

- url: /.*
  script: web.py

inbound_services:
- mail
```

twitter.py ends with:

```
application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
                                     [('/twitter', Process_new_DM)],
                                     debug=True)

def main():
    run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: There is a stdlib library named [`email`](http://docs.python.org/library/email.html) already; perhaps you need to rename yours to prevent the wrong library being loaded?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Thanks for the well-formatted and detailed question.  Best of luck!

Comment: @ldbrooke: Heh, that was a stab in the dark. I've posted it as an answer now that we know that was it. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a standard library named [`email`](http://docs.python.org/library/email.html) as well; it is being loaded before your local module is being found.

Rename the module to something else and it'll work.